# iOS: UI testing + continuous integration?

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, ui-testing

I'm looking for a UI-testing framework for iOS projects which can be used together with Jenkins. I already found NativeDriver (https://code.google.com/archive/p/nativedriver/) and Frank (https://github.com/moredip/Frank), but no information about the combination with CI.

As I had problems with both of them and did not get them to work perfectly, I'd like to know if it pays out to invest more time. CI is a must for our project, so I would like to know if someone has experience with UI-testing a Xcode project together with CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried any CI with it, but I know [KIF](https://github.com/square/KIF) can be integrated with Jenkins using [WaxSim](https://github.com/square/waxsim) and it's pretty good for UI automation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very new one just out called [Zucchini](http://www.zucchiniframework.org/). The authors started with the idea of CI and ensured that it can be run from Jenkins/Hudson. It's a BDD framework which uses Coffee script to map stories to UI. I saw a demo of it at a recent conference and it looked good. I would say that the only cons to it I see are a lack of documentation and the requirement to learn Coffeescript.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a blog post some time ago on setting CI with Frank and Bamboo - http://p0deje.blogspot.com/2011/10/continuous-integration-for-ios-app-with.html.

I also implemented iOS part of Ruby bindings for NativeDriver - http://rubygems.org/gems/nativedriver. So, the same Bamboo setup can be applied to NativeDriver, just change the backend from Frank to NativeDriver.